# How to run junit system integration tests in kubernetes/service mesh?

Tags: kubernetes, junit, servicemesh

We have a service mesh/kubernetes working via the terminal, showing all the different pods with their different name spaces. Inside of each pod, you can console in and see the app.jar.

Recently, boss/client asked how we can run the various SYSTEM INTEGRATION tests for any particular JAR from the service mesh/kubernetes command line. Google says to use 'mvn clean install', 'javac' or 'java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.2.jar --class-path target --select-class '. These all fail for various reasons (mvn not present, javac not present, jar says that port is in use. Of course the port is in use, the same aforementioned jar is using it).

When I look at a pod in Gitlab (or Intellij) I see all the tests it has. But how I can run these SYSTEM INTEGRATION tests from the pod console? Ideally a command to run all tests, that would make things a lot easier.

edit:
lol at the heat in the comments. I clarified with the boss, she said that we want to run system integration tests from the service mesh, not unit tests. These pods are not isolated, some of them depend on each other.

Comment: That makes no sense as a request - you run the unit tests on the source code, _then_ build and deploy the container if they pass. They shouldn't even be included in what's in the deployed jar.

Comment: your boss/client needs a reality check, imho...

Answer (score 0):

Generally the comment from the user [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) could be an answer to the question:

> That makes no sense as a request - you run the unit tests on the source code,  *then*  build and deploy the container if they pass. They shouldn't even be included in what's in the deployed jar.

If you need to test an application, do so before deploying it. You should have a separate environment where you will test your application, and only use Kubernetes when the application is working properly. You can of course use some CI type solution. Look at this page - [Running JUnit tests with GitLab CI for Kubernetes-hosted apps](https://medium.com/flant-com/junit-gitlab-ci-kubernetes-27921ec36823).

EDIT
If you are looking for a solution to make integration testing with Kubernetes you can read a couple of docs. It all depends on what specifically you want to test. I present several possibilities:

- [Overcome Kubernetes Application Integration Testing Challenges with Telepresence](https://www.getambassador.io/resources/overcome-kubernetes-application-integration-testing-challenges-telepresence/)
- [How we approached integration testing in Kubernetes, and why we stopped using Helm tests](https://kyma-project.io/blog/2020/1/16/integration-testing-in-k8s)
- [Testing Kubernetes deployments within CI Pipelines](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2020/06/17/testing-kubernetes-deployments-within-ci-pipelines/)

Comment: I edited my post to clarify we want to run system integration tests, not unit tests